# Add a costum column in log in Tortoise Subversion (TSVN)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

we want to document who reviewed a specific commit.

For that reason, we tried to modify the log messages with that instruction: https://www.fullstackagile.eu/2011/12/30/lightweight-code-reviews-using-tortoisesvn/

When we commit, we see another field to add the reviewer, but we don't see the column. How can we add this column or another individual column?

[image: message log]